# How to decide the priority of chemical reaction?

Tags: chemistry

If there are more than one chemical reaction in a container, how to decide the order among those reaction.

For example, there are three chemicals in one beaker, called A,B and C. The chemical A can react with B, and A can react with C too. Is there any rule to decide the priority of the chemical reaction?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about [chemistry.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

All possible reactions will occur simultaneously. So if we have A+B->D and A+C->E, then we will always get mixture of all five compounds.

It is possible, yet a complex task, to determine the different ratios of the compounds in equilibrium. This depends on the *reaction rate* and *equilibrium constant* of each reaction, which in turn depend on the reaction itself as well as the reaction conditions such as *temperature* or *pressure*.

If you need more details or have any further questions about this, I recommend asking at [chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).